# Serial software not working

Tags: serial-port

I have Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and I would like communicate through USB-UART.
I plugged my converter into my PC and found it at /dev/ttyUSB0.

I searched for software and found 'minicon', edited the setting and tried it, but nothing happens. No data sent or received. The LED on the board doesn't blink when I transmit data, so it's clearly not working.

Then I downloaded 'PUTTY', it's better, because it has GUI, but when a press the "Open" button, nothing happens.

Then I found 'screen' and it works. Same settings, same baudrate, same port. It works, the others don't.

One could say my problem is solved, because I got a working software, but I am really curious what is the reason behind it (and I would rather use a software with GUI). Can anyone help me out?

I always use sudo and tried changing permission of /dev/ttyUSB0.

Comment: Instead of using sudo, you should add your user to the `dialout` group.

Comment: I added, but it did not solve the problem.